# Mysql sum result is duplicated

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the sales total of each day / store with the following query:

```
SELECT st.name, SUM(sa.val), sa.sale_date FROM sales sa
  INNER JOIN employee e ON sa.employee_id
INNER JOIN store st ON e.store_id
GROUP BY st.name, sa.sale_date
ORDER BY sa.sale_date
```

But it generates duplicated results for the SUM.

```
+---------+-------------+------------------------+
|  name   | SUM(sa.val) |       sale_date        |
+---------+-------------+------------------------+
| Store 1 |         800 | July, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
| Store 2 |         800 | July, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
+---------+-------------+------------------------+
```

It should be:

```
+---------+-------------+------------------------+
|  name   | SUM(sa.val) |       sale_date        |
+---------+-------------+------------------------+
| Store 1 |         100 | July, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
| Store 2 |         300 | July, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
+---------+-------------+------------------------+
```

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0faa35/40

Comment: Perhaps you need a where condition `where sale_date = '2015-07-29' ` and remove the `sale_date` from group by... if this is not what you are looking for then you need to clarify the question a bit more.

Comment: Its not giving duplicate results its giving right results according to the group by logic if you need to get sum of 29th then put a where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join conditions are incomplete. See the changed "ON" clauses in the statement below:

```
SELECT st.name, SUM(sa.val), sa.sale_date FROM sales sa
  INNER JOIN employee e ON sa.employee_id=e.id
  INNER JOIN store st ON e.store_id=st.id
GROUP BY st.name, sa.sale_date
ORDER BY sa.sale_date
```

Comment: Can't believe it was just that... 
Thanks, I'll tag this as answer when is possible.

Can you please explain what happened ?

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos The `ON` clause works the same as a `WHERE` clause. It needs to be a *condition*. I reccomend you read http://www.khankennels.com/blog/index.php/archives/2007/04/20/getting-joins/ and http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ to understand how join conditions reduce the number of rows generated (and in your case affects the aggregate sums)